# 7.1 Suround Sound through one 3.5mm jack

Tags: windows, audio, sound-card, adapter

I have a headset (a Logitech G430) for which I have lost the adapter. There are two plugs on the headset: mic and audio. The adapter enabled 7.1 surround sound on the headset. I am looking for a way to redirect all 7.1 sound channels into this one jack using software, no hardware.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headset you use uses a USB adapter that (I'd guess) performs the 7.1 audio generation. A standard 3.5mm can only do mono or stereo. Many audio cards can do a "fake" 5.1 or surround sound but they use echo and reverb effects via software that normally comes bundled with your sound card.

To get the true 7.1 you'll need to purchase the USB adapter

Comment: Now that I think about it, it doesn't make sense that an adapter would come bundled with the headset if sound cards could generate the surround. :) Thanks.

Comment: Your particular headphones did come with a USB adapter of some sort so they are capable of 7.1 (according to Logitech)...

Comment: They certainly are capable of 7.1. I used the Logitech Gaming Software test.